# PHP doesn't get HTML Form values

Tags: php, html, sql, database, post

I'm working on a school project with HTML / PHP. Now I came across the problem our PHP file, /bid.php, doesn't retrieve our HTML Form's input data. 
When submitting the form we get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in D:\School\IN\USBWebserver v8.5\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\bid.php on line 4

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT:

I have edited my code as of now as I have found from various sources. It currently doesn't respond with any errors. Making me wonder what the problem is as the inserted values won't show up in my database.
veiling **.php**

```
<form method="post" action="/bid.php">
<input type="text" name="bod" placeholder="bod">
<input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="naam">
<input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Nummer">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
$bod = $_POST['bod'];
$naam = $_POST['naam'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
?>
```

bid.php

```
<?php
$bid = isset($_POST['bod']) ? $_POST['bod'] : false;
$name = isset($_POST['naam']) ? $_POST['naam'] : false;
$item = isset($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : false;

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw'); 
mysql_select_db ('veiling'); 
$sql = "INSERT into personeel (name, bod, item) 
VALUES ('$name', '$bid', '$item')"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql); 
mysql_close ($connect); ?>
```

### Old code below

veiling html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/bid.php">
<input type="text" name="bod" placeholder="bod">
<input type="text" name="naam" placeholder="naam">
<input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Nummer">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

bid php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, usbw);
mysql_select_db ('veiling')
$bid = $_GET['bod']
$name = $_GET['naam']
$item = $_GET['item'] 
$maxbid = mysql_query(SELECT MAX(bod) FROM veiling WHERE item=1)
if $bid =< $maxbid then
exit
else
INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item)
VALUES ($bid, $name, $item)
// SQL
echo('Gefeliciteerd '$name', het bod op item ' $item ' van €' $bid 'is succesvol toegevoegd')

?>
```

And our database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veiling` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `bod` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `item` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Learn php, the mistakes here are so very simple, with just a quick glance I've spotted multiple simple syntax errors.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do here. Anyways I'm just asking for a little help.

Comment: try to add some ";" of every line but thats not only thing , sorry you need so much help

Comment: @DemiënDrost You don't come to SO to LEARN php, you do that through tutorials and what not, the issues with your code are so simple that it makes me think that you haven't done much research beforehand.

Comment: This is like an SQL-injection fest! Stop using **mysql_*** functions since they are deprecated, and start using **mysqli_*** or **PDO** instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ;'s at the end of your lines.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, usbw);
mysql_select_db ('veiling');
$bid = $_GET['bod'];
$name = $_GET['naam'];
$item = $_GET['item'];
$maxbid = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(bod) FROM veiling WHERE item=1");
$maxbid = mysql_fetch_array($maxbid);
if( $bid =< $maxbid[0] )
{
    die();
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item) VALUES ($bid, $name, $item)");
// You should escape the parameters with mysql_real_escape_string.
// SQL
echo 'Gefeliciteerd '$name', het bod op item ' $item ' van €' $bid 'is succesvol toegevoegd';
}
?>
```

This code should work.

You should also note that the mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5. I reccomend you use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your statements missed the required semi-colon. I have edited your code thus:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, usbw);
mysql_select_db ('veiling');
$bid = $_GET['bod'];
$name = $_GET['naam'];
$item = $_GET['item'];
$maxbid = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(bod) FROM veiling WHERE item=1");
$maxbid = mysql_fetch_array($maxbid);
if( $bid <= $maxbid[0] ) //notice the <= not =<
{
   die();
}
else
{  //note the single quotes around $name and $item
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item) VALUES ($bid, '$name', '$item')");

//note the dot(.) concatenating your string with the variables
echo 'Gefeliciteerd '. $name. ', het bod op item '. $item. ' van €'. $bid. 'is succesvol toegevoegd';
}
?>
```

This code should work

Answer (score -1):

You've missed semi-colons starting at

```
mysql_select_db ('veiling')
```

Comment: And that's just for starters. Several other syntax errors like with the **if** block, implicitly typed sql queries...

Comment: Well @Daan, my answer solves the immediate problem he has. He stated an error message and technically, it's the right answer. Why downvote?

Comment: Technically it's all wrong just have a look at this line: `if $bid =< $maxbid then`

Answer (score -2):

Too many errors in your code I have changed few try this
change,

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, usbw);
mysql_select_db ('veiling')
$bid = $_GET['bod']
$name = $_GET['naam']
$item = $_GET['item'] 
$maxbid = mysql_query(SELECT MAX(bod) FROM veiling WHERE item=1)
if $bid =< $maxbid then
exit
else
INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item)
VALUES ($bid, $name, $item)
// SQL
echo('Gefeliciteerd '$name', het bod op item ' $item ' van €' $bid 'is succesvol toegevoegd')

?>
```

like this,

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, usbw);
mysql_select_db ('veiling');
$bid = $_GET['bod'];
$name = $_GET['naam'];
$item = $_GET['item'] ;
$maxbid = mysql_query(SELECT MAX(bod) FROM veiling WHERE item=1);
if ($bid =< $maxbid) 
exit
else
INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item)
VALUES ($bid, $name, $item)
// SQL
echo('Gefeliciteerd '$name', het bod op item ' $item ' van €' $bid 'is succesvol toegevoegd');

?>
```

Comment: Your change doesn't help very much.

Comment: @Daan please point anything to him so that he understand his mistake don't simple down vote everyone...

Comment: You should give a more complete answer than this.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @ayyanar-g I my errors have now shifted to line 11 "INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item);"

Comment: change that line to mysql_query("INSERT INTO veiling (bod, naam, item) VALUES ('.$bid.', '.$name.', '.$item.')");

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't make any difference. I have now inputted some new code.